Authorization token is not working in Rest Assured
package com.automation.tests;

import static io.restassured.RestAssured.*;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import io.restassured.response.Response;
import io.restassured.specification.RequestSpecification;

public class AspenTest {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        JSONObject churnUsageBody = new JSONObject();
        churnUsageBody.put("customer_id", "c096");
        
        RequestSpecification sp = given().baseUri("http://192.168.180.12:4000/")
        .header("Content-Type", "application/json")
        .header("X-CSRFToken", "EZpbczzL5yiBHKT0fn2PcfPszp0IfHwPLn3pmXJYA8BX8bH6Gn6ILrlAJPSuX1uq")
        .header("Authorization", "Token d2618176b9b9aed6dc0a9cb3a1ebfe1c4c8831ed999bdce4432e061aa56f672f")
        .body(churnUsageBody.toString());
        
        Response rs =  sp.post("churn/app/usgscore");
        System.out.println(rs.asPrettyString());
    }
}

I am trying to run the api after adding the authorization token, I am getting the below error, even the token is proper and this api is working in postman also.
{
    "detail": "Authentication credentials were not provided."
}


can you show screenshot of how you set up this header in postman?

To debug the issue, I have two suggestions for you:

please check whether the API expects the word "Token" before the actual token. Some APIs expect "Bearer" before the actual token.
{.header("Authorization", "Bearer d2618176b9b9aed6dc0a9cb3a1ebfe1c4c8831ed999bdce4432e061aa56f672f")}

Log your request by enabling logging ( log().all()) in rest assured to debug your request and verify that the headers and body are being sent correctly. Resource


